# Projector Doesn't Show Windows

Tags: dual-boot, display, display-resolution, presentation, projector

I'm having an issue with connecting my laptop with the projector via VGA port.

My laptop runs both Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

The projector is working fine with Windows 7, but with Ubuntu only the wallpaper and half of top panel bar are visible.

Every application I opened was not displaying on the projector (Nautilus, LibreOffice Impress, etc.) but it's working fine when the slide show of a presentation is played.

What exactly is the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu sees something you connect via VGA as a new display because there are a lot of people who use a second display attached to their laptops when they're working with them.

You can see where the display which is your projector is by launching "Displays" from the dash. If you didn't change anything, it's probably to the right of your laptop screen meaning that if you move your mouse pointer out the right-hand side of your laptop's screen, it will appear on the projector. You can of course drag windows there.

If you want the same to be displayed on your laptop screen and on the projector, just check the box "Mirror displays".

LibreOffice automatically uses the first display as the screen for notes, preview of the next slide, time, etc., and the second one (which is your projector) for the actual presentation. That's why LibreOffice behaves the same under Ubuntu as it does under Windows, even though the displays are mirrored under Windows and aren't under Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and the reply. 

I'll try that when I again connect my laptop to the Projector and will definately get back to you if any problem occurs.